# Binding a Listbox to a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, observablecollection

So I am trying to bind the following ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> _PlacesOrCities;
    public ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> PlacesOrCities
    {
        get { return _PlacesOrCities; }
        set { _PlacesOrCities = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PlacesOrCities"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _PlacesOrCities = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>();
    }
}
```

To the following xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="lbPlacesCity" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(gms:MainWindow.ViewModel).PlacesOrCities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:ListBoxItem">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource  MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}" Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the codebehind as such:

```
public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

And upon firing a button click event- I try to set the values of the observable collection using a in memory list:

```
private void StateProvince_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _CurrentSelectionPlaces = Canada.Provinces
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Abbreviation == _SelectedStateProvince_ShortName)
        .Place.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var currentSelectionPlace in _CurrentSelectionPlaces)
    {
        ViewModel.PlacesOrCities.Add(currentSelectionPlace);
    }    
}
```

But it seems like none of the items are being added to the collection. Am I binding it incorrectly?

I've tried quite a few solutions but none of them seem to change the result- where no items in the list are being loaded into the collection properly.

EDIT: 
It may be worth noting that the `ListBoxItem` as seen in the `ViewModel` is a custom model:

```
public class ListBoxItem
{
    [J("Name")] public string Name { get; set; }
    [J("PostalCodes")] public string[] PostalCodes { get; set; }
    public Visibility Visibility { get; set; } = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: You should see binding errors in the `Output` window when running the application. Try and figure out what's wrong from there

Comment: No errors are being generated in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to fit to the MVVM pattern, so the population of the list should occur at viewmodel level and not in the view's code behind.

You mentioned that you use a click event, instead of doing so, try to bind the command property of the button to a command in the viewmodel, see this link with an explanation of several types of commands and how to use them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

In the other hand, if you already set the data context in the window constructor, to bind the ListBox items source you only need the name of the property to bind, "PlacesOrCities":

```
<ListBox Name="lbPlacesCity" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacesOrCities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:ListBoxItem">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource  MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}" Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It would also be recommendable trying to load the items in the list without any template, you can use ListBox DisplayMemberPath property to display the name, and once you are able to load items, apply the style.

Also in the way you use ObservableCollection, you actually need to replace the whole collection instead of adding to fire RaisePropertyChanged, try a normal property instead.

```
public ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> PlacesOrCities {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>();
```

Modifying the collection will update the UI, so whenever you use Add or Clear, the UI should know it.

Hope it helps.